# cscript.exe doesn't read unicode script (UTF-8)

Tags: unicode, utf-8, wsh

simply save the following in notepad using UTF-8

```
msgbox "你好"
```

double click or run it from command line

```
D:\>cscript.exe /u test-unicode.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\test-unicode.vbs(1, 1) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Invalid characte
r
```

is there any way to run the unicode script in Windows Script Host?

Comment: Windows uses  UTF-16 for most unicode representations, so the file would need to be saved in that form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cscript.exe can run scripts saved using [Unicode] (seems UTF-16).

Comment: Use `cscript /u`. See the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cscript).