# How can I solve this VBS code encoding problem?

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbs script. It opens excel file, write something , saved than closed. The problem is: the excel file path name contain a special character. What could be a problem and how can I resolve?

Thank you in advance!

```
strWBFullName= "Munkafüzet1.xlsx"

If Not CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(strWBFullName) Then
  MsgBox "File """ & strWBFullName & """ does not exist or is not available.", vbCritical, "File Not Found"
  WScript.Quit
End If

Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oXL.Visible = True
Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(strWBFullName)

oWB.Worksheets(1).Select
oWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Select
oWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "K"

WScript.Sleep 5000

oWB.Save
oWB.Close
oXL.Quit
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf3Fi.png)

Comment: Does your script work when the file does NOT contain special characters? If not, then it could be a current directory issue. If so, then try saving your script as Unicode (UTF-16).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cscript.exe doesn't read unicode script (UTF-8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236085/cscript-exe-doesnt-read-unicode-script-utf-8). Looks like your script is saved in Unicode (UTF-16) you'll need a special switch `/u` when running the script to support it.